# regexp mysql function

Tags: php, mysql, regex, isbn

I have several PHP regex that I use for matching ISBN 10 but I can't find one that is compatible for MySQL's `REGEXP`, can someone help me match ISBN 10 in MySQL?

I have tried this one (works in PHP but not in MySQL)

```
"^(97(8|9))?\d{9}(\d|X)$"
```

Here are some values that I am running this regex against:

```
ISBN10: 0470945176
by Paul D. Kimmel
Publisher: John Wiley &amp; Sons
Copyright year: © 2011
```

and

```
Thomas E. Creighton (Author)
ISBN-10: 0471153028 
Publisher: Wiley-Interscience; 1 edition (April 8, 1999)
2878 pages
```

Comment: @eggyal i added some values which i am running it against

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\d` shortcut doesn't exist in MySQL regular expressions.  Use the `[[:digit:]]` character class instead:

```
"^(97(8|9))?[[:digit:]]{9}([[:digit:]]|X)$"
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec493/1/0).

Comment: If there is a trailing X, it should be upper-case. So if using this regexp, use `REGEXP BINARY "^(97(8|9))?[[:digit:]]{9}([[:digit:]]|X)$"` so that the check is case-sensitive.

Comment: The whole thing can also be abbreviated to `^(97[89])?[0-9]{9}[0-9X]$`.